# Unable to retrieve data from array of character inside structure

Tags: c

I am using below code in one file

file 1

```
//structure is global 
struct abc
{
    char var;
    char *a[5];
}*p;
struct abc q;

int main()
{
    char t[] = "sample"
    p = &q;
    p->a[0] = &t[0];
    p->var = 10;
    printf("var = %d, string  = %s\n", p->var, p->a[0]);
    func();
    exit(0);
}
```

But if I try to access the structure member (`a[]`) in `func()` that is in another file I don't get the data that is assigned in another file (above).

file2

```
int fucn()
{
    char var1;
    var1 = p->var;
    printf("var1 = %d\n", var1);
    //since i am unable to copy p->a[0] to some other string i am trying to print the  contents of p->a[0].
    printf("a = %s\n", p->a[0]);
}
```

program crashes executing the second `printf` but I can print the content of `p->var` which is assigned in some other file.

Comment: You have defined `p` as a global variable? And it's declared `extern` in the other source file? Please create a complete example (known as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) to show us.

Comment: It is hard for us to tell what you are doing here. Please post your complete code including main function, other functions, etc.

Comment: Oh, and `q` and `t` are not a local variable in a function unrelated to the function in the second source file, I hope?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do but `p->a[0] = &t[0];` would be more readable if written as `p->a[0] = &t;` or even `p->a[0] = t;` IMHO

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem The `&t` will only work because `t` is an array. If it was a pointer (or an array decayed to a pointer) it would not work.

Comment: The problem is your `t` variable is local to your first file, when your in your second file, `t` is no longer valid hence your program crashes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: indeed it won't, but seeing it this close to `char t[] = "some const";` kind of rules out `t` being a pointer

Comment: @T.V. If `t` is a global variable, then it's okay. It's okay even if `t` is a local variable, *if* the function in the other file is called from the function where `t` is defined. This is why we need to see some complete code as otherwise it's impossible to reliably answer this question, just guess.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, if `t` is a global variable but looking at the code, I highly doubt that is the case.

Comment: Here is what i am trying to do.

Comment: Edited the program as mentioned above.

Comment: I just copied your code into a blank project and ran it. It works just fine. Only thing wrong I see about your code is that you do not have a return value in the func() function and you mispelled the function name. Just little technicalities that are probably unrelated to your issue. What IDE are you running this in? I was using Visual Studio 2005 to test this.

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE. The problem for me is that i can access other members of the structure but i am not able to access a[0]. Accessing a[0] leads to crash

Comment: Does anyone know if Eclipse has any issues with char pointers, references, or accessing structure's data members? I only worked in eclipse a bit but that was a year ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like below is what you need.

An include file.

```
prompt> cat foo.h
struct abc {
    char var;
    char *a[5];
};

extern struct abc *p;
```

main function

```
prompt> cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "foo.h"  

struct abc q, *p;
extern int func();

int               
main()
{     
    p = &q; 

    /*
     * Using strcpy after allocating memory.
     */

    p->a[0] = malloc(strlen("zero") + 1);
    strcpy(p->a[0], "zero");

    /*
     * strdup is equivalent to malloc and strcpy
     */

    p->a[1] = strdup("one");

    p->a[2] = "two";
    p->a[3] = "three";
    p->a[4] = "four"
    p->var = 10;

    printf("main var = %d, string = %s %s %s %s %s\n", 
        p->var, p->a[0], p->a[1], p->a[2], p->a[3], p->a[4]);
    func();

    return(0);
}
```

func function

```
prompt> cat func.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"  

int             
func()
{     
    int r;

    r = printf("func var = %d, string = %s %s %s %s %s\n", 
        p->var, p->a[0], p->a[1], p->a[2], p->a[3], p->a[4]);

    return(r);
}
```

Compile and run

```
prompt> gcc mainc.c func.c
prompt> a.out
main var = 10, string = zero one two three four
func var = 10, string = zero one two three four
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. In my program that i have provided above i have used only one string but my application requires multiple strings and that's the reason i used array of pointers to hold multiple stings. I don't know the reason why i can read other member data of the structure but not the stings in another file.

Comment: I have updated the code to show five strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead copying to character pointer like this p->a[0] = "zero" can you try copying using strcpy() to p->a[0] and try to read p->a[0] in another file.

Comment: I have updated code to show an example of malloc+strcpy and strdup